# What is the naming pattern in Better Call Saul?

Tags: better-call-saul

Better Call Saul's episodes feel like they have a pattern in their naming convention to me, but I can't quite figure it out and I haven't been able to find any articles on it.

> 1. Uno
> 2. Mijo
> 3. Nacho
> 4. Hero
> 5. Alpine Shepherd Boy
> 6. Five-O
> 7. Bingo
> 8. Rico
> 9. Pimento
> 10. Maro

They are almost all short words that end in 'o', but I figure the pattern must have more meaning than that.

Does anyone know what the pattern is?

Comment: It should be noted that episode 5's original title was *Jello* and actually inspired this pattern but the title had to be changed (probably because Jell-O is a registered trademark).

Comment: Episode 10 should be "Marco" not "Maro"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this Quora post](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-all-the-names-of-the-episodes-of-the-first-Season-of-Better-Call-Saul-end-with-an-o) this started out as a coincidence, but the creators liked the idea.

> The show creators Vince Gilligan and Peter Gould mentioned in one of
>   the insider podcasts that this started out as a coincidence, but once
>   they noticed it for a few episodes they tried to do it intentionally
>   for all of them because they knew fans would notice.
>
> The episode titled "Jello" was changed because they didn't have rights
>   to it since it's trademarked.

The source of this information is [this insider podcast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/better-call-saul-insider-podcast/id966297954?mt=2).

Comment: So there really isnt much reason? They just like the `-O` endings?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Apparently there is no deep meaining behind it.

Comment: Not sure this is worthy of a separate answer, but each of the titles also have something do do with the episode, thus establishing a pattern. For example, Mijo is a Spanish concatenation of the words "mi hijo", or "my son", which Tuco's grandmother keeps calling him. Nacho is the central character of the episode with the same name. Hero? Saul's the hero on the local news. Five-O deals with Mike's past life as a cop. RICO, they find a RICO case. Pimento is the type of sandwich Mike brings for the job he's going on.

Answer (score 6):

Although the "-o" thing seems to be meaningless (but the writers did intentionally do it for fun); there seems to be another easter egg.

If you take the first letter of every episode name in season 2; you get an anagram that spells "Fring's back". This seems more than just coincidence.

I'm waiting to see if season 3 bring any easter egg with it.

---

**Edit** As per the request in the comments, a list of season 2 episode names.

- **S**witch
- **C**obbler
- **A**marillo
- **G**loves off
- **R**ebecca
- **B**ali Ha'i
- **I**nflatable
- **F**ifi
- **N**ailed
- **K**lick

> SCAGRBIFNK
>      FRINGSBACK

Comment: This is really interesting! Any chance you could include the list in your answer, just to enhance it a bit?

Comment: @Longshanks: Added

Comment: "This seems more than just coincidence." Uhm... http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/04/better-call-saul-gus-frings-back-title-anagram-finale

Comment: And if you rearrange the first letters of the season _three_ episode titles, you get "WES MCFLOSS", a [beloved Breaking Bad character](https://twitter.com/WesMcFloss) who [totally shows up in _Better Call Saul_ season 5](https://www.reddit.com/r/betterCallSaul/comments/foaxj7/wes_mcfloss/).